# MacOS requiring different OS version vs Info.plist

Tags: macos, info.plist

I'm building a MacOS app bundle, and I've specified a minimum OS version (10.10) using the `LSMinimumSystemVersion` key in the `Info.plist`. The app itself works fine, as long as we run it on OS 10.12. But if we try to launch it on 10.11, we get an error: *"You can't use this version of the application  with this version of OS X. You have OS X 10.11.6. The application requires OS X 10.12 or later."*

I've investigated everything I can find related to OS version checking and I can't figure out what's going on. We get the same result even if I leave out the `LSMinimumSystemVersion` entry completely. We've tested on multiple Macs running 10.11 and it fails consistently, so it's not some machine specific bug. The actual binary (the executable buried inside the app bundle) runs fine on 10.11, it's just the app bundle that fails.

I'm building the app using a makefile, not Xcode (for reasons too long to go into here). Maybe there's some extra step I need to add?

Attached below is the Info.plist (slightly censored):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>*********</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>***************************</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>*******.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>*********************</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>***************************</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>**.**.**</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>**.**.**.**</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.10.0</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>**********************</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I think you'll want to set "deployment target" to the lower version you want to be able to run it on...

Comment: I said I wasn't using Xcode.

Comment: What difference does that make? I didn't imply you had to...

Comment: "Deployment target" is an Xcode setting. I don't know how to set it from the command line (possibly the option Brendan suggested is the equivalent).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

Comment: ... ENVP= MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.x can be set in a makefile ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you compiling/linking with `-mmacosx-version-min`? Add `-mmacosx-version-min=10.10` to your compiler/linker options if you're not already

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I've never heard of that option, and neither has Google; it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. How on earth did you find out about it?

Comment: Aha, I discovered why I couldn't find it when I searched. TIL Google doesn't like search strings that start with a minus sign.

Comment: hmm i don't understand why this helped. Could someone explain it to me? OP states "the executable buried inside the app bundle runs fine on 10.11, it's just the app bundle that fails". So how does changing compiler flags (which presumably built that executable buried inside the app bundle) affect the success of the app bundle itself?

Why doesn't the executable fail without the flag? Why does the bundle succeed with it? Thanks!

Comment: haha but this fixed it for me also. i don't understand *how*, but fix it it sure did.